# Access 2010 error when moving focus to subform or acSaveRecord

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, subform

So I have a Form in Acess 2010 with two subforms to manage one-to-many relationship, for Projects and Tasks, they are bound to two linked tables on SQL Server so whenever I load a project, the tasks are listed on the subform.

Lately I have been encountered an error [on primary key violation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haE7R.png) whenever I move from a field on the main form to any area of the subforms. This tells me that the primary form is trying to save whatever it was loaded, but instead of UPDATE, it's trying to INSERT.

There is no code or event that I can see (like before or after update) that may do that specific command. There is a Save button on the form, this button is using `DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70` and it produces the same error.

Is there a way to indicate Access to use UPDATE instead of INSERT?

I have been looking all around but don't seem to find any related fix.

Thanks to everyone!

EDIT: I have tried removing the primary key on the linked table and the error goes away, but as suspected, it is inserting duplicates every time I move to a different record or click on the subform. So if anyone have a clue on the record navigation behavior and how to configure it, I would appreciate very much!

Comment: If you're opening the form in Add mode, it will default to Insert. Likewise opening in Edit, defaults to Update. You haven't shown any code or how your forms are linked so we can't help much here

Comment: Acctually you are helping more than you think, I don't have much experience with Access forms, I can see that there is no actions to perform in the main form code, when I load the form it does not specify the method, so I tried to use `DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria, acFormEdit` to try what you mentioned (I was not aware of this, thanks) but seems that it does not change the case... the form stills throws the error whenever y click anywhere on the subform or try to move to the next record... it still tries to insert and then violates the PK.

Comment: I'm using bound forms by the way.

Comment: check that the relationship key between the two tables is not being changed when you try to enter a new value. for example if you have an FK that auto populates on the sub form when you try to add or edit a value, make sure that is still referencing the right Key on the parent form.

Comment: Thanks Erick, I have removed the subform from the form, the tables have no FK, so now I just have my main form bound to the main table and it has it's PK (it's of type text btw... which I don't like but I cannot change it) and the problem is still showing, it tries to insert every time I try to move to another record on the form.

Answer (score 0):

If there are triggers on the SQL tables, it may be the trigger that is calling the INSERT statement rather than the front end.

Comment: I checked but there are no triggers on the tables. Thanks for the help.